# QML exposing c++ property via var causing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of null"

Tags: qt, qml

```
//MyProxy1.hpp and MyProxy2.hpp
Q_PROPERTY(QObject* support READ support NOTIFY supportChanged)

MyProxy::setSupport(const QSharedPointer<Support>& support)
{
  m_support = support;
  emit supportChanged();
}

QObject* MyProxy::support()
{    
  return m_support.data();
}

private:
    QSharedPointer<Support> m_support;


//main.cpp
...
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myProxy1", &myProxy1);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myProxy2", &myProxy2);
...

//MyItem.qml
Item {
    property var support

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: support.contracts //contracts is a QList<QObject*>
            Text { Text: modelData.description }
        }
    }
}

//MyPage1.qml
MyItem {
    support: myProxy1.support //support is a QObject* class
}

//MyPage2.qml
MyItem {
    testProperty: myProxy2.support //support is a QObject* class
}
```

My goal is to use MyItem various time with different c++ properties of the same type (Support). The fact is that when I am inside MyPage1/2.qml and the support property of myProxy1/2 is modified in the c++ side, application outputs this -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'contracts' of null.
contracts is a QList<QSharedPointer<Contract>> exposed as QList<QObject*>.
If I use myProxy1/2.support.contracts directly in MyItem.qml the error disappear. Why?

Comment: I see no property named `contracts` in your code at all. Anyway, please provide [mcve] so we can maybe run and test the code.

Comment: I added some log and I found that the problem is in the setSupport function. When I do m_support = support, m_support is deleted because it's not used anymore. This cause the qml to point to a null object for a millisecond before the supportChanged() is emitted. How can i fix it?

Comment: `model: support == null ? [] : support.contracts`

Comment: @DavidK.Hess thank you